# Why does Memory<T> not have an indexer, while Span<T> does

Tags: c#, .net-core

`Span<T>` and `ReadOnlySpan<T>` have an indexer that allows `byte x = mySpan[3];` and also allow ranges, like `Span<byte> = mySpan[2..5];`.

Memory and ReadOnlyMemory on the other hand allow ranges, like `Memory<byte> x = myMemory[2..5];`, but there is no indexer that allows `byte x = myMemory[3];`. We're forced to get a Span from the memory first, like `byte x = myMemory.Span[3];`.

Why is that?

Comment: If you look at the [design notes](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/blob/master/docs/specs/memory.md#:~:text=Memory%3CT%3E%201%20Introduction.%20Memory%3CT%3E%20is%20a%20type%20complementing,are%20described%20in%20this%20section.%20More%20items...%20), one of the lines near the end under "Issues/To-Design" says `Should we add an indexer to Memory<T>?`. Looks like they haven't decided to do that yet (if ever).

Comment: Reading that entire design notes page, it seems `Memory<T>` doesn't have the problems that `Span<T>` has, which is that they cannot be stored. Span has a more direct approach to a particular memory location, which makes them less performant during garbage collection, so the design team opted for disallowing storing them, to reduce the number of live such objects. Memory, on the other hand, doesn't have this problem, but you get additional cost in constructing Spans. If the Memory type gets an indexer, I would expect this cost to incur on every access. Probably better with the current approach.

Comment: However, as with most "Why is that" type of questions, you probably need a response from one of the design team members, otherwise, since they haven't actually documented why they haven't added it, we can only make guesses, and then this question should probably be closed as "Primarily based on opinions".

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen interesting to see that apparently it was a conscious decision to not implement the indexer on the Memory types. I hope someone of the C# design team reads this question and can shed some light on that design choice.

Comment: See also [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/11018#issuecomment-417642419): an indexer would be expensive, and therefore presumably users should be encouraged to get a span *once*, and then use that for all indexing operations.

Comment: @canton7 Yes, that's what I took from the design notes.

Comment: Agreed. By forcing to go back to Span, it removes many of the reasons why people would use Memory instead of Span, like being able to use it in high order functions for example.